# How can I transition an element between a relative position to an absolute position?

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm working on a portfolio site and I had this cool idea that the landing page will have the name in the middle and then when I select a route the page will turn into a navbar.

The problem is, in order to do this I either have to position the navbar items absolutely, which I don't want to do, or I need to center the name in the middle of the screen relative to its original position, which is not desirable either.

[This is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhgwj.gif)

I'm using Vue with Tailwind, but a vanilla HTML solution would help.

This is my code:

```html
<template>
  <header
    class="bg-black/25 py-3 transition-[max-height] duration-1000 ease-in-out max-h-screen h-screen justify-center"
    :class="{
      'flex max-h-20': !isHomePage,
    }"
  >
    <div
      class="w-5/6 flex justify-between items-center"
      :class="{ 'h-screen': isHomePage }"
    >
      <router-link to="/" :class="{ 'flex space-x-2 items-end': !isHomePage }">
        <div
          class="text-3xl font-semibold transition-all absolute duration-1000 left-1/2 top-1/3 -translate-y-4"
          :class="{
            'relative !translate-y-0 !translate-x-0 left-0 top-0': !isHomePage,
          }"
        >
          Aby
        </div>
        <div
          class="text-2xl font-medium transition-all duration-1000 absolute left-1/2 top-1/3 translate-y-4 -translate-x-4"
          :class="{
            'relative !translate-y-0 !translate-x-0 left-0 top-0': !isHomePage,
          }"
        >
          Isakov
        </div>
      </router-link>
      <router-link to="/other">click</router-link>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

I tried to position the navbar items absolutely, but this caused problems with making the component responsive.

Comment: According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#position-property), no. You can't animate the position property

Comment: @BernardBorg I know that, but the question is there a way to animate to the relative positive. Maybe I'm approaching this all wrong?

Comment: You can transition/animate their relative position - you'd just have to _calculate_ by how much you need to move the element from its default position in the nav bar, for it to appear in the center of the screen then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take some steps to apply a transition that changes the 'position' css property. Here is the function that does it with a relative positioned element:

```
function positionTransition(element) {
    var rectBefore = element.getBoundingClientRect(); //get old coordinates
    
    //change positioning:
    element.style.position = "absolute";
    element.style.left = "50vw";
    element.style.top = "50vh";
    
    var rectAfter = element.getBoundingClientRect(); //get new coordinates
    
    //calculate the difference:
    var xDiff = -(rectAfter.x - rectBefore.x);
    var yDiff = -(rectAfter.y - rectBefore.y);
    
    //translate back, so that the absolute positioned element seems to be in the old place:
    element.style.transform = "translate(" + xDiff + "px, " + yDiff + "px)";
    
    //finally, make the transition, which works because it remains in position: absolute
    setTimeout(function() { //without the timeout, transition is ignored
        element.style.transition = "transform 1000ms ease-in-out";
        element.style.transform = "";
    }, 10);
}
```

I know what you're thinking, but don't worry. The change in position and translate back is instantaneous, there is no flicker!

**EDIT1**

I built a full example into the following snippet:

```js
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var element = document.querySelector(".the-changing-span");
            positionTransition(element);
        }, 1000);
    });
    
    function positionTransition(element) {
        var rectBefore = element.getBoundingClientRect(); //get old coordinates
        
        //change positioning:
        element.style.position = "absolute";
        element.style.left = "50vw";
        element.style.top = "50vh";
        
        var rectAfter = element.getBoundingClientRect(); //get new coordinates
        
        //calculate the difference:
        var xDiff = -(rectAfter.x - rectBefore.x);
        var yDiff = -(rectAfter.y - rectBefore.y);
        
        //translate, so that the absolute positioned element seems to be in the old place:
        element.style.transform = "translate(" + xDiff + "px, " + yDiff + "px)";
        
        //finally, make the transition, which works because it remains in position: absolute
        setTimeout(function() {
            element.style.transition = "transform 1000ms ease-in-out";
            element.style.transform = "";
        }, 10);
    }
```

```css
    .the-changing-span {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    span {
        border: 1px solid #AAA;
    }
```

```html
    <span class="a-simple-span">
        stays
    </span>
    <span class="the-changing-span">
        changes
    </span>
```

Comment: tried playing with this for a while... Didn't work for me still. All this does for me is jump the name to the center then get it back with a transition..

Comment: this happened to me when I forgot the minus sign. Anyway, I added a snippet with the full HTML and CSS. I forgot to mention the initial position: relative of the element, and now it is built into the example. Feel free to ask me if anything goes wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this can't be achieved for time being according the docs.

---

### Reference

#### 1.  [w3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#position-property)

> Animatable:   no

#### 2. [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#formal_definition)

> Animation type:  discrete